# NSAttribuedString lines top & bottom spacing changed on iOS 13.4

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, nsattributedstring, uifont

On the update of iOS 13.4, the top & bottom spacing of the `NSAttributedString` lines not the same not.

This is the same code run on iOS 13.3 & iOS 13.4.

iOS 13.3
[image: iOS 13.3]

iOS 13.4
[image]

Here is the code for generating the attributed string with this style:

```
struct Utility {
    static func customAttributedString(first: String, second: String, firstColor: UIColor = .white, secondColor: UIColor = .purple, size: CGFloat = 60) -> NSAttributedString {

        let styleAttributes = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        let stringAttributes:[NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font : (UIFont.drukBold?.withSize(size))!,
                                                              .foregroundColor: firstColor,
                                                              .paragraphStyle: styleAttributes]

        let stringSecondAttributes:[NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font : (UIFont.drukBold?.withSize(size))!,
                                                                    .foregroundColor: secondColor,
                                                                    .paragraphStyle: styleAttributes]

        let string = "  \(first)  ".uppercased()
        let secondString = "\n  \(second)  ".uppercased()
        let mutable = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: stringAttributes)
        let secondMutable = NSMutableAttributedString(string: secondString, attributes: stringSecondAttributes)
        mutable.append(secondMutable)
        var startIndex = mutable.string.startIndex
        while let range = mutable.string.range(of: "\\n", options: .regularExpression, range: startIndex..<mutable.string.endIndex) {
            mutable.addAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.black, range: NSRange(Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: startIndex, upper: range.lowerBound)), in:  mutable.string))
            startIndex = range.upperBound
        }
        mutable.addAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.black, range: NSRange(Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: startIndex, upper:  mutable.string.endIndex)), in:  mutable.string))
        return mutable
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have the same top & bottom spacing in both versions?

EDIT: In fact,  I was playing to `NSAttributedString` to know what is causing this, and I just found out that using the system font, will have the wanted behavior with no problem. I don't know why the custom font behavior changed between versions? maybe they changed the way to handle the custom fonts

Comment: I am not sure but have you tired "styleAttributes.alignment = .center"

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir Yes I have tried it and it centers the whole text in the `UITextView`. But the line spacings are always the same.

Comment: I know. I had the same problem for textfield's place holder. I used custom font. I had calculated text size and redrawn placeholder. Maybe there is different solution.